# How to redirect to particular view controller from push notification when app is in terminated mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to redirect the app to particular view controller from push notification received. But yet, i am not able to get which delegate method will be called. Please guide.

Below is the code i have tried so far. i have tried in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but doesn't working.

```
 if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if (apsInfo) { //apsInfo is not nil
        [self performSelector:@selector(notificationClickedInNotificationPanel:)
                   withObject:userInfo
                   afterDelay:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh replace with?

Comment: isn't it looks same?

Answer (score 2):

I did something very recently, but it's in `Swift` but should be very similar if you want to do this in OC.

**Hint:** `didReceiveRemoteNotification`  will not get called if your app is terminated, the only method that gets called is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can do something like this

```
if let launchOpts = launchOptions as [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? {
            if let notificationPayload = launchOpts[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary {

                 let apsBody = notificationPayload["aps"] as? NSDictionary
                 if(apsBody != nil){
                 // here you can either read value from the `apsBody` dictionary 
                //OR just push the respective controller you want to push
                 }
            }
        }else{
           //go with the regular flow
        }
```

Do know this when your app is terminated you have no instance of `navigationController` so you might want to make sure you have an instance of a navigation controller to push your view.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

// Called when App is in Foreground // Using the data received in the notification you can call the desired view controller

    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

and,

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

// Called when App is not in  Foreground // Using the data received in the notification you can call the desired view controller
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: objective c only please

Comment: have implemented code in both of them but not working, can't even check whether they are called or not.

Comment: They are called , to check simply goto your app target  ->Edit Scheme -> Wait for executable to be launched. Add breakpoints in these methods and click on your notification

Comment: when to launch the app. App is closed, then push received, then tap on notification panel. So, when to launch the app.

Comment: First, please let me know is the possible to redirect in app to any screen from notification tap when app closed?

Comment: When user clicks on notification then ,if your app is not running it will launch your app and you will get the control in designated push notification delegate method. Then using the data in notification playload/dictionary , you can open any controller of your choice. Wanna see it in action download "The tribune" ios app

Answer (score 0):

You should do it both in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveRemoteNotification, they are called at different times.  The first is called when the app is completely closed when the notification is clicked, the second is called when the app is open and in use.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {

            self.animal_id = [dictionary objectForKey:@"animal_id"];
            self.notificationText = [dictionary objectForKey:@"alert"];
            self.soundFile = [dictionary objectForKey:@"sound"];

            if ([self.animal_id length] > 0) {

                NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
                numberOfBadges -=1;

                if (numberOfBadges < 0) {
                    numberOfBadges = 0;
                }

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];

                doNotShowAlert = YES;
                [self showPetDetails:self.animal_id];
            } else {
                doNotShowAlert = NO;
            }

        }

    }

    return YES;
}
```

And Here:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    numberOfBadges -=1;

    if (numberOfBadges < 0) {
        numberOfBadges = 0;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];

    self.animal_id  = [userInfo objectForKey:@"animal_id"];

    NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    self.notificationText = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
    self.soundFile = [aps objectForKey:@"sound"];

   [self showPetDetails:self.animal_id];
}
```

showPetDetails goes out to the database to get the detail information to display.  When it has it, it calls another method to display the detail view:

```
PetDetailViewController *notificationController = [self.rootNavigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"petdetail"];
notificationController.petDetail = petDetail;
notificationController.currentImage = nil;

[self.rootNavigationController pushViewController:notificationController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the app has killed, You can find the push notification payload from the `launchOptions`

Here is the reference for more info: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey/1622967-remotenotification